How to mount a file into a helm subchart pod file system in kubernetes?
The problem is to add a file with config data into Kubernetes pod described by helm subchart developed by third party.
I've read number of comments saying this can be solved easily by introducing a configMap with proper data. The problem is: it is not clear how the added data gets into the subchart in question. With the following chart structure where it is necessary to put a config map and where/how to use it? Many thanks in advance!
myChart
  - charts
    subChartToAddFile.tgz
  - templates
    configMap.yaml
  Chart.yaml
  values.yaml

Where configMap.yaml contains the config map with a file to be mounted like
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: init-scripts-config
data:
  init-key.sh: |
    sleep 10;

Chart.yaml contains the dependency
apiVersion: v2
kubeVersion: '>=1.14.4'

name: myChart
dependencies:
  - name: subChartToAddFile
...


It all the depends on the content of your subchart. It looks like init-scripts-config configMap is present in the subchart and you are just overriding it. The top level chart should override the init-scripts-config in the subchart.
If the ConfigMap name is dynamically populated in the subchart you will likely have to include that value in the top level values.yaml file.
Example top level values.yaml excerpt:
subChartToAddFile:
global:
configmapname: myconfigmapname
You can always test it with:
helm template chart/directory ...

More info here.
✌️

Finally solved by referencing the map in parent chart values.yaml like
subChartToAddFile:
  server:
    volumes:
      - name: init-key
        configMap:
          name: init-scripts-config
          items:
            - key: init-key #map key name
              path: init-key.data
    volumeMounts:
      - name: init-key
        mountPath: /userconfig

The section is subchart dependant.
